# Camera App : Save images to internal memory and access those images using content uri?

Tags: android, image, camera, internal-storage

I know many threads exists for the same. But My problem is a bit different I guess.

I am trying to capture images from my custom camera app using surfaceview holder. There I can get the data after takepicture. I am trying to store the data in the internal storage using getFilesDir(). But the images are not getting stored there.  The data can be huge considering the number of images the burst mode can capture.

Please suggest me a way to save hundreds of images efficiently into memory and load their thumbnails in grid view so that user can select the images he/she wants to save to SD-card.

I have tried lazy-loading of images which are stored on SD-card. But I want to use internal storage as user wont be able to see those images in gallery.

Comment: If you want to hide the files from the user which are on sd card, simply create a file called ".nomedia" in the folder where in you save your image files.

Comment: yes but some devices wont be having external SD-card in that case i have to use internal storage.

Comment: What is your strategy for clicking images in burst mode?